# Eloi Mara as breeding stock

Tags: the-time-machine-2002

In the 2002 film *The Time Machine*, the Über-Morlock says to Dr. Alexander Hartdegen that Mara is being kept alive to be used as breeding stock for other colonies or something like that. Did he mean that she was going to another Morlock colony to be used for breeding with the Morlocks at that colony or was she going to breed with that colonies Eloi 'cattle'?

Comment: Assuming it's anything like the 1960 version, she was going to be bred with other Eloi.

Answer (score 4):

The implication seems to be that Mara was taken as a surrogate, to be used as a "vessel" for the Morloks to create a new Morlok colony nearby.

Note that there are no Morlok females shown in the film. Surrogacy may be their only way of breeding.

> **Alex:** *So it's not enough that you hunt them down like animals.*
>
> **Overlord:** *That's their role here.*
>
> **Alex:** *To be your food.*
>
> **Overlord:** **Yes. And for those who are suitable, to be *breeding vessels* for other colonies.**

---

Interestingly, in the earlier [2000 draft script](https://sfy.ru/?script=time_machine_2002), Mara was being taken away to *become* a Morlok

> Alexander discovers Mara, almost lost in the incredibly Baroque chaos
>   of the chamber.  She is hanging on a wall, leather straps holding her
>   in place.  Filthy plastic IV tubes connect her to some chugging
>   medical equipment.
>
> Alexander reaches up to grasp her hand, can just reach her.
>
> **ALEXANDER:** *Mara...*
>
> Mara weakly raises her head -- a shocking sight -- already her skin is
>   becoming strangely translucent, her veins beginning to show through.
>
> **ALEXANDER:** *No...*
>
> Mara tries to speak, cannot.  Alexander stands for a beat, holding her
>   hand.  Then, without turning:
>
> **ALEXANDER:** *Why?*
>
> **OVERLORD:** *We have lost the capacity to reproduce.  But the species must continue.*

Comment: I am not sure what is implied: Does the Uber Morlock plan to mate with an Eloi to give birth to another Uber Morlock? Surrogates carry fertilized eggs to term, but without Morlock females, no eggs. Perhaps there are many kidnapped Eloi, some of whom, shudder, are forced to mate with hunter Morlocks also?

Comment: @releseabe - I believe the implication is that she's going to be *directly transformed* into a Morlock, not that she'll be used as a brood mare

Comment: wow, i sure disagree based on her being physically attractive, although the iv-tubes in the script i guess imply some procedure; but in the movie, it seems like she wd be mated with by the uber morlock.

Comment: @releseabe - In the script she's starting to look like a Morlock, hence my assumption that they're making her into one.

Comment: But the actual stuff on screen I think u wd agree does not imply that. The whole idea of eloi being transformed into morlocks sure is not a compelling one to me and is counter to Wells, I am pretty sure. The uber morlock we see is basically human and no reason could not mate with eloi, possibly giving rise to offspring which are also ubers. so many Hunter morlocks that they do not breed makes no sense. fortunately don't have to worry about this for nearly a million years.